# Given a matrix $A$ and what it maps two vectors to, is $0$ an eigenvalue of it?

Tags: linear-algebra

Studying for my Algebra exam, and this question popped out with no solution in a previous exam:

> Given a matrix $A$ such that $A \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -4 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix},\ A \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ -6 \end{pmatrix}$.
>
> (I) Is $0$ an eigenvalue of the matrix?
>
> (II) Find a matrix like that, where the sum of its' eigenvalues is $0$.

So I (think) solved (I) but have no clue for (II).
Here's my solution for (I):

> $A \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + A \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = A \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -4 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ -6 \end{pmatrix} = 0$, and then, the vector $v = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$ supplies that $Av = 0v = 0$ meaning that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with an eigenvector $v$.

Comment: Your solution for $I$ is correct. For $II$: Which invariant of a matrix corresponds to the sum of eigenvalues?

Comment: The $trace$ perhaps?

Comment: Bingo. So use the two given values to find the first two columns, and use the trace to satisfy the eigenvalue sum condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for (I) looks good.

Good for (II) might be to note that
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\-6\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-3\end{bmatrix}
$$
which gives the first two columns of $A$:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&x\\2&4&y\\-3&-6&z\end{bmatrix}
$$
The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. Thus, if the sum of the eigenvalues is $0$, we need $z=-5$.  $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If a matrix $A$ has column vectors $a_1,..,a_n$, then
$$A\cdot e_i=a_i$$
where $e_1=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\ \vdots}$, $e_2=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\ \vdots}$, $e_3=\pmatrix{0\\0\\1\\ \vdots}$...